# is it dangerous for me to install steam through playonlinux?even if I do not install it by the playonlinux server?

Tags: wine, playonlinux

Before installing applications of playonlinux appears a scary warning.
Even if I download the windows steam manually instead of letting the playonlinux download to me, can it be dangerous? Or am I paranoid? can I get malware?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to get malware through Steam if you install a game that includes malware, but it's no more likely than on Windows.

Comment: As long as you do not run it as root yoh should be fine

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to download the installer through PlayOnLinux. All it does is download the installer from steam. Thus, is no different than you downloading it yourself.

As with any software, there is little to no danger if downloaded from an official source.

Steam does have a linux version. Is there a specific reason for using the Windows version under WINE?

Note: FYI -- PlayOnLinux, Does not actually host any games. It is merely a script engine that automates the process of creating a WINE prefix, installing the software, and creating launchers. The only thing actually downloaded from PoL is the script. Personally, I find that WineHQ's app data base is better than PoL.

Comment: The main reason to use the Windows version of Steam is to get Windows-only (or Windows and Mac-only) Steam games under Wine.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex -- thank you. I thought steam versions were dependent on steam not the OS behind it.